# UITableView in UIScrollview, multiple pages & one tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a question regarding a UITableView inside a UIScrollView.

This is the situation:

I have a ListViewController which shows a few events in a UITableView. If the users taps an event, this event is shown in some kind of DetailViewController. No big deal so far.

The thing is: the client wants to be able to swipe right and left to see previous and next events (in DetailViewController). And this is where I struggle a bit.

So I made a DetailViewController with a UIScrollview containing a UITableView. Scrolling works, pagecounter works, there's hardcoded data in my cells, so far so good.

My problem: The data from every event has to be loaded and shown in this tableview.
So: If the user taps Event1, all the Event1-data has to be shown in the tableview. When the users swipes left though, the data from Event2 should be visible (in the same tableview). Repeat this for a few events.

How can I achieve this?

I tried something like this in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (pageControl.currentPage == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Page 0"; //These will all be arrays in the future
}
else if (pageControl.currentPage == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Page 1";
}
else if (pageControl.currentPage == 2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Page 2";
}
else if (pageControl.currentPage == 3) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Page 3";
}    
else if (pageControl.currentPage == 4) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Page 4";
}

return cell;
```

But this does not work, it only shows me Page 0 in every cell. 
Weird thing is:  if I pull a cell too high or low (so it's not visible anymore), the cell shows me the correct value. I've made a video of it, it's pretty hard to explain. Video: http://cl.ly/EgfB

I tried calling reloadData but that didn't work either.

Is this even possible without creating a tableview for every Event?

BTW: I've tried [PanelTableView](http://www.honcheng.com/2010/11/Open-Source-PanelTableView-for-iOS-developers) but I had a really hard time getting that thing to work, so I'd rather do it without.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the table data source in the detailViewController and also let it know the current event to show. A custom init function can be implemented in detailViewController

```
- (id) initWithEvent: (NSInteger) eventNum dataSource: (NSArray*) dSource
{
    if(self = [super initWithNibName: @"detailViewController" bundle: nil])
    {
        self.dataSource = dSource;
        self.currentEvent = eventNum;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then pick up correct event by indexing the dataSource.